# Identification of polygon edges

Tags: general-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

In Klein's famous example of regular 14-gon made of 336 copies of (2,3,7) triangles, he used identification for edges such that side 2i+1 is identified with side 2i+6 (mod 14). But I wonder how could he find the identifications? Do you know the clue? Thank you!